# Entity Framework 6 One-To-Many With Hierarchy Per Table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

First here's the info:

I have the following models:

```
public class Prerequisite : BaseModel
{
  public string Contract { get; set; }
  public bool Ignorable { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<PrerequisiteParameter> PrerequisiteParameters { get; set; }
}

public class PrerequisiteParameter : BaseModel
{
  public virtual Prerequisite Prerequisite { get; set; }

  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrerequisite : Prerequisite
{
  public ProductVersionComponent ProductVersionComponent { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVersionComponent : BaseModel
{
  public ICollection<ProductPrerequisite> ProductPrerequisites { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following configuration classes:

```
class PrerequisiteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Prerequisite>
{
  public PrerequisiteConfiguration()
  {

    this.Property(p => p.Contract).HasColumnName("Contract");
    this.Property(p => p.Ignorable).HasColumnName("Ignorable");
    this.HasMany<PrerequisiteParameter>(p => p.PrerequisiteParameters)
      .WithRequired(pp => pp.Prerequisite)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
  }
}

class ProductPrerequisiteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductPrerequisite>
{
  public ProductPrerequisiteConfiguration()
  {
    this.HasRequired<ProductVersionComponent>(pp => pp.ProductVersionComponent).WithMany(pvc => pvc.ProductPrerequisites);
  }
}

class PrerequisiteParameterConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PrerequisiteParameter>
{
  public PrerequisiteParameterConfiguration()
  {

  }
}

class ProductVersionComponentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductVersionComponent>
{
  public ProductVersionComponentConfiguration()
  {
    this.HasMany<ProductPrerequisite>(pvc => pvc.ProductPrerequisites).WithRequired(pp => pp.ProductVersionComponent).WillCascadeOnDelete();
  }
}
```

The DB structure:
[image: Database Structure]

Now the Prerequisite table is the table per hierarchy table. This makes the Id for the ProductVersionComponent nullable.

I'm having the following problems:

```
Prerequisite prerequisite = context.Prerequisites.Include(p => p.PrerequisiteParameters).Where(p => p.Id == prerequisiteId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Calling the above code will return the prerequisite for the *prerequisiteId*, but *prerequisite.PrerequisiteParameters* will always be null.

I've fired up Sql Profiler and can see the query it generates:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Project2].[Contract] AS [Contract], 
[Project2].[Ignorable] AS [Ignorable], 
[Project2].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Project2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Project2].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
[Project2].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
[Project2].[ProductVersionComponent_Id] AS [ProductVersionComponent_Id], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project2].[Prerequisite_Id] AS [Prerequisite_Id], 
[Project2].[Key] AS [Key], 
[Project2].[Value] AS [Value], 
[Project2].[Created1] AS [Created1], 
[Project2].[CreatedBy1] AS [CreatedBy1], 
[Project2].[Modified1] AS [Modified1], 
[Project2].[ModifiedBy1] AS [ModifiedBy1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Contract] AS [Contract], 
    [Limit1].[Ignorable] AS [Ignorable], 
    [Limit1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Limit1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
    [Limit1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Limit1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    [Limit1].[ProductVersionComponent_Id] AS [ProductVersionComponent_Id], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Prerequisite_Id] AS [Prerequisite_Id], 
    [Extent2].[Key] AS [Key], 
    [Extent2].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Extent2].[Created] AS [Created1], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy1], 
    [Extent2].[Modified] AS [Modified1], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Contract] AS [Contract], 
        [Extent1].[Ignorable] AS [Ignorable], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
        [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersionComponent_Id] AS [ProductVersionComponent_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Prerequisites] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N''ProductPrerequisite'',N''Prerequisite'')) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0) ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PrerequisiteParameters] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Prerequisite_Id]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=13
```

It returns the following:

```
Id Discriminator   Contract    Ignorable   Created CreatedBy   Modified    ModifiedBy  ProductVersionComponent_Id  C1  Id1 Key Value   Created1    CreatedBy1  Modified1   ModifiedBy1 Prerequisite_Id
13  ProductPrerequisite INFRASTRUCTURE_PROCESSOR_COUNT  1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   1   1   MIN 2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13
```

To me this shows the query loading both the prerequisite and the only parameter it has. I've tried a different Id and was able to get back multiple rows when there are multiple parameters tied to a single prerequisite.

Somehow this makes cascading deleting fail because of the FK restraint. When I try the following it fails:

```
context.Prerequisites.Remove(prerequisite);
```

It generates the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[Prerequisites]
WHERE (([Id] = @0) AND ([ProductVersionComponent_Id] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=13,@1=1
```

It's as if it isn't recognizing the parameters as children.

Now if I go and create a *ProductPrerequisite*, give it properties and link a *ProductVersionComponent* to it, and save the object it will populate the database with the correct data and keys!

```
ProductPrerequisite newPrereq = this.CreateProductPrerequisite(dbComponent, prerequisite);

context.Prerequisites.Add(newPrereq);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If I load a *PrerequisiteParameter* navigate to its *Prerequisite* property it will be correctly lazy loaded. If I then go to the collection *PrerequisiteParameters* it also will be lazy loaded!

I'm really scratching my head on this one.